# why does the controllers action have HttpRequestBase, and the viewpage has HttpRequest?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My methods take HttpRequestBase as arguements, and I am finding it strange as to why the Actions in Controllers have access to HttpRequestBase but the view page's have HttpRequest.

Is there a reason for this or just something that was not thought through?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

View pages have access to the MVC HttpContext through `ViewContext.HttpContext`, which is an `HttpContextBase`.

The seemingly dual access is just due to the way ASP.Net works.  When you look at `Request.HttpContext`, this is the ASP.Net pipeline's injection of the original `HttpContext`.  This is accessible in any HttpHandler, whether it's an MVC controller or view, or a WebForms page or ashx.

Answer (score 2):

ViewPage inherits from System.Web.UI.Page and I'm pretty positive all of the HttpRequest members are inherited from that:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504962.aspx